# catkin build stuck on rospack failure

Tags: python, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

POST EDIT

I'm installing on El Capitan (os x 10.11.1) and it appears that a lot of people are having issues with this version of os x without a solution. In my scouring the web I've found a handful other people running into the same issues.

ORIGINAL

`$ catkin build  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

fails with:

```
...
[python_orocos_kdl] ==> '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j' in '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl'
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/python_module_PyKDL.dir/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart0.o
In file included from /Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart0.cpp:7:
In file included from /Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/sipAPIPyKDL.h:11:
/usr/local/include/sip.h:32:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
         ^
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/python_module_PyKDL.dir/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart1.o
In file included from /Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart1.cpp:7:
In file included from /Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/sipAPIPyKDL.h:11:
/usr/local/include/sip.h:32:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/python_module_PyKDL.dir/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart0.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/python_module_PyKDL.dir/PyKDL/sipPyKDLpart1.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/python_module_PyKDL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[python_orocos_kdl] <== '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j' failed with return code '2'
                                                                                 
Finished <== visualization_tutorials          [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Starting ==> rospack                                                            
Finished <== viz                              [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Starting ==> rostime                                                            
Finished <== gencpp                           [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Starting ==> xmlrpcpp                                                           
Finished <== geneus                           [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Starting ==> pr2_description                                                    
Failed   <== python_orocos_kdl                [ 1.6 seconds ]                   
Finished <== genlisp                          [ 1.2 seconds ]                   
Finished <== genpy                            [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Finished <== class_loader                     [ 1.4 seconds ]                   
                                                                                
[rospack] ==> '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/rospack/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j' in '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/rospack'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib', needed by `/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/librospack.dylib'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:72:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[rospack] <== '/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/build/rospack/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j' failed with return code '2'
                                                                                 
Finished <== rostime                          [ 1.3 seconds ]                   
Finished <== xmlrpcpp                         [ 1.2 seconds ]                   
Finished <== pr2_description                  [ 2.7 seconds ]                   
Failed   <== rospack                          [ 3.3 seconds ]                   
[build] Runtime: 23.2 seconds 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 219, in main
    sys.exit(args.main(args) or 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/cli.py", line 296, in main
    summarize_build=opts.summarize  # Can be True, False, or None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/build.py", line 756, in build_isolated_workspace
    set_error_state(error_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/build.py", line 695, in set_error_state
    executors[x].should_shutdown = True
KeyError: 0
```

I know Python is installed. I even added the location to `.bash_profile` like so:

```
echo "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

But I'm still stuck. How can I get past this issue?

*mid 2015 mbp OS X 10.11.1*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222323/catkin-build-stuck-on-rospack-failure/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-12-11**:
Are you sure Python.h file exists?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2015-12-11**:
`find / -name "Python.h"` finds the file in a number of different spots. Is there a specific one I need to check for?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-14**:
Have you tried using `catkin_make_isolated` instead? `catkin build` is still in beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No luck with any of this so far. I ended up getting everything installed after I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 ran from a virtual machine using these tutorials:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ros%20install%20hydro

http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/

PS- I had luck on 14.04.03 with ROS indigo and rgbdslam. There were numerous errors but I eventually figured them out. Still have camera issues though.

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-05**:
I was able to get everything installed on el capitan. I'm not sure what I did exactly beside ignoring one error saying that gazebo could not be detected (second to last step: `$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y`)